# CMake does not produce Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm using VS Code on windows. I have a simple CMakelists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

When I run it, it produces a bunch of build, vcxproj, etc. But it does not create any Makefile. So when I run `make` I get: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should generate it with cmake -G "Unix Makefiles". It seems like now you have Visual Studio as a default build system. You can check all possible build systems with cmake --help.